# Is there any debugger area styling mechanism in xcode

Tags: xcode

Basically the debugger area comes in random font in the XCode(some bold some light).Is there any styling possible on printing the logs and all.I mean increase font,size,color  specified via code.

Know the theme setting in preferences.I am looking for something via Obj-C code.Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide me the reason for downvote and show me the right options

Comment: It is not immediately obvious that you need to click on the 'console' tab to see the debug area font settings, even though they appear adjacent the 'source editor' area. I for one expect a 'console' to be a separate window so I did not look in there until I saw this question. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 8):

The font and color of the debugger console can be changed in the Xcode preferences.

[image: Console styling]

Comment: Note that debug area fonts are under the 'Console' Tab